# io.konik.PdfHandler constructor error

Tags: c#, .net, ikvm

I have a c# dotnet 4 solution with one main wpf project which
refer as project a class library with references the local IKVM.*.dll version Version=8.0.5449.1 and ZUGFeRD.NET.dll version 1.0.0.0. When trying to do

```
PdfHandler handler = new PdfHandler();
```

I'm getting the next error :

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=""
  Source=IKVM.OpenJDK.Core
  StackTrace:
       at java.util.ServiceLoader.LazyIterator.nextService()
       at java.util.ServiceLoader.LazyIterator.next()
       at java.util.ServiceLoader.1.next()
       at io.konik.PdfHandler..ctor() ...
```

The strange part is that if I use the the IKVM.*.dll and
ZUGFeRD.NET.dll in first project and remove the second project, the example from [Github](https://github.com/konik-io/ZUGFeRD.NET-Example/tree/master/KonikNetExample) 
works.  Do you have any ideea? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem. This problem could be solved by adding

```
ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(typeof(ObjectFactory).Assembly);
```

before using the ZUGFeRD.NET framework.

I put this code in the constructor of my own ZUGFeRD class.

Comment: Totally works. Saved my afternoon, at least. Thanks a bunch.